# Convert non symmetric matrix to square matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a non symmetric dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

I want to convert this dataframe to a square matrix in R. Ideally I want the result to look like this so I can use it in other applications. (Note: this is just a fragment of the real df that has more than 50 columns).

[image]

Comment: post the data instead of images

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10bM3h1FGZW-XsD8Y08yDKrD8C0SR9ip2/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example, we could loop over the columns that are not the first column, and do a `==`, convert to binary with `+` and update the dataset columns

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) +(df1[[1]] %in% x & !is.na(x)))
```

Comment: Actually after inspection I think there is a problem because some rows towards the end are all just 0. Could it be due to the positions? As you can see in the example everything is quite disorganised

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios I thoughtt you wanted to do elementwise comparison.  If not, change it to `%in%` from `==`

Comment: It's still not catching many names that should be there. Ideally I want to look for each name in ID and if its found in (any row) in column x write a 1. Otherwise a 0.

Comment: @Amaranta_Remedios Are you doing `+(df1[[1]] %in% x & !is.na(x))` because earlier it was `x %in% df1[[1]]`